# Why does the NullPointerException occur on the Selenium driver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception, testng

I have two separated Selenium Webdriver's classes. The class I made first runs without any error but the second class throws the NullPointerException. 

The error points out the bellow line `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,40);`. not only for the `WebDriverWait` the NullPointer exception throws if `driver` is instantiated in a line of code. eg `Actions action = new Actions(driver);`.

The NullPointerException throws on the above code also. But the the first class doesn't have kind of issue.

The class I made first

```
package Initiate;

import dataProvider.CommonClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class NewBOM {

    public WebDriver driver;
    By newBomButton = By.id("btnUpdate");

    public NewBOM(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver=driver;
        this.CreateNewBOM();

    }

    public void CreateNewBOM(){
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
        wait.pollingEvery(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        WebElement newBomBtn = driver.findElement(newBomButton);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(newBomBtn));
        action.moveToElement(newBomBtn).click().build().perform();
    }
}
```

The second class which throws the nullpointer exception

```
package Initiate;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


public class NewBOO {
    public WebDriver driver;

    public NewBOO(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver=driver;
    }

    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,40);
        System.out.println("Test print");
    }
}
```

TestNg class for the class I made 1st

```
import Initiate.NewBOM;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class CreateBOM {
    public WebDriver driver;

    private NewBOM objNewBOM;

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void clickOnNewBOMButton(){
        objNewBOM = new NewBOM(driver);
        objNewBOM.CreateNewBOM();
    }

}
```

TestNg class for the class I made 2nd

```
import Initiate.NewBOO;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class CreateBOO {
    public WebDriver driver;
    NewBOO objNewBOO;
    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void temporyTest() throws InterruptedException {
        objNewBOO = new NewBOO(driver);
        objNewBOO.test();
    }
}
```

Complete Error Messages

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:787)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.<init>(FluentWait.java:96)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:71)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.<init>(WebDriverWait.java:45)
    at Initiate.NewBOO.test(NewBOO.java:17)
    at CreateBOO.temporyTest(CreateBOO.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)


===============================================
Default Suite`enter code here`
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I test both testNg classes individually and both classes are independent. But 1st class runs wothout any null pointer exception and 2nd class throws a nullpointer exception.

Comment: Where do you initialize the `driver`?

Comment: Which driver ? I initialized it on both classes

Comment: I don't see initialization anywhere in the code you provided.

Comment: Can you show me an example how to initialize the driver

Comment: Initializing must be something along the lines of public WebDriver driver = new WebDriver(), maybe with some additoinal options. The first class will run because it does not use the driver. Probably if you do, it will fail just the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code didn't init WebDriver and try to use it, so it throws the `NullPointerException`.
In TestNG, you can use @BeforeSuite, @BeforeTest, @BeforeClass to initialize your dependencies. The example below shows how to init the webdriver in 'BeforeClass'.

```
import Initiate.NewBOM;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class CreateBOM {
    public WebDriver driver;

    private NewBOM objNewBOM;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setupClass(){
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void clickOnNewBOMButton(){
        objNewBOM = new NewBOM(driver);
        objNewBOM.CreateNewBOM();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Check your driver initiated, In case if driver is initiated two times so you may get the error where as second driver initiated .
Eg. Actions act= new Actions(driver);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).